# Ajax calls not Updating SQL Server database linked to ASP.NET MVC web page

Tags: jquery, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc, azure

The following pieces of code are sections from an ASP.NET MVC web page that I am creating through an Azure server. The page contains a table that is linked to a Microsoft SQL Server database table (acts as an updating copy of the database table) that I also created.

Currently, manual changes to the database result in changes to the table on the web page. I have an "Add" button that uses a modal with user inputs ('sbtn' in code below is for the modal's submit button) to add rows to both the web page and database tables. On my localhost, this button would successfully update both tables, however on the Azure server this button does not affect the database table in any way, a (temporary) row is added to the table on the web page, and no errors are shown. I cannot figure out why the database table will not update with each press of the button.

I am trying to get the button to update the database table. Any help would be appreciated. I can post additional code (from related files) if needed.

Portion of script:

```
// Add Button (opens modal)
btn.onclick = function () {
    addmodal.style.display = "block";
}

// Submit Button (updates tables and closes modal)
sbtn.onclick = function () {
            var table = document.getElementById("mainTable");
            var tag = document.getElementById("tag").value;
            var server = document.getElementById("server").value;
            var frequency = document.getElementById("frequency").value;
            var objInputCheckBox = document.createElement("input");
            objInputCheckBox.type = "checkbox";
            var newdata = { Tag: tag, Server: server, Frequency: frequency };
            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            cell1.appendChild(objInputCheckBox);
            cell2.innerHTML = tag.replace(/\s+/g, '');
            cell3.innerHTML = server.replace(/\s+/g, '');
            cell4.innerHTML = frequency.replace(/\s+/g, '');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Content("~/Home/Index/AddRow")",
                data: newdata,
                success: function (data) {
                    addmodal.style.display = "none";
                },
                error: OnError
            });
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddRow(TableDataWeb newData)
{
        using (var dbContext = new TableDB())
        {
            dbContext.TData.Add(newData);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error???

Comment: No error messages, the database just won't update (I'm rather certain that the URL called by the ajax command is correct).

Answer (score 0):

I use Url.Action for my ajax paths. Try this instead of "@Url.Content("~/Home/Index/AddRow")":

```
  var url = "@Url.Action("AddRow", "Home")";
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: newdata,
            success: function (data) {
                addmodal.style.display = "none";
            },
            error: OnError
        });
```

I'm assuming "Home" is your controller name

Comment: This doesn't change anything. I don't believe that the 'url: ' is causing the issue (I have tried numerous forms already).